# Django path in pycharm

Tags: python, django

PS C:\Users\rajla> django-admin startproject mymall .
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- django-admin startproject mymall .
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoun  
  dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

this is the issue i am facing i am totally confused and i am getting headache so please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
python -m django-admin startproject mymall
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).